# GWT compile error with jdk1.5.0_22, works fine with jdk1.5.0_13

Tags: gwt, ant, java-5

I am working on a tomcat web app (tomcat 5.5.30) which consists of GWT widgets (GWT 1.7.0).

While running the ant build, the compilation fails with following error:

...
ERROR] Unexpected internal compiler error
     [java] java.lang.StackOverflowError
     [java]     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1891)
     [java]     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:479)
...

The JDK version I am using is jdk1.5.0_22. Interestingly, the build completes successfully with JDK version 1.5.0_13. I've also tried to build with jdk1.5.0_18, but it fails with same error message.

I searched the web, and found [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-web-toolkit/JcmrGCRdJfQ). I tried the solutions but none works for me.

I am unable to find out, what has changed after jdk1.5.0 update 13 that my build is failing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you update either gwt (current version 2.5) or your jdk (current version 7u11) ?

Comment: Can you not just use latest jdk but set the compilation level to java 5?

Comment: @AndreasFrische - No, it's a maintenance project. I'm just doing some enhancements.

Comment: @SSR - I'll have to check, the server, our webapp runs on, has java runtime version 1.5 only.

Comment: what stack size did you set? did you try to compile for only one browser target?

Comment: Following jvm arguments are set in build.xml:
<jvmarg value="-Xmx512M"/>
<jvmarg value="-Xss128k"/>

I am compiling for firefox 3.6, ie8 and safari.